# Nice way of constructing ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ..., 'z']

Tags: javascript

I want to construct the array `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ..., 'z']` in a clean way. The best I have found is

`'a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z'.split(' ');`

I wonder if there is a more "programmatic" approach.

Comment: There are more programmatic ways to do it, like what alex suggested, but the trade-off is that these will almost certainly be slower (and less obvious in purpose, if you’re glancing at the code) than the more direct approaches (like what @Guffa suggested).

Comment: `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, this can be shortened a bit to:

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
```

But let me think of another way ...

**EDIT** ... nope, I don't think there's a faster way than Guffa's

Answer (score 27):

Why not just a literal array?

```
var chars = [
  'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
  'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'
];
```

#### Edit:

I had to test, and this is *a lot* faster than splitting a string: [jsperf.com/arraycreation](http://jsperf.com/arraycreation)

Comment: I only needed to compute `chars` once, so the time I would be saving with your solution is 0, but readability is increased with `aefxx`'s solution.

Answer (score 12):

> I wonder is there is a more "programmatic" approach?

You *could* do it with code...

```
var chars = [];
for (var i = 97; i < 123; i++) {
    chars.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YdDzu/).

You could whip up a range type function to do it. This would at least encapsulate the ugly-ness of generating this inline...

```
// Create a range of letters.
var createAlphaRange = function(start, end) {
    var chars = [],
        startOrdinal = start.charCodeAt(0),
        endOrdinal = end.charCodeAt(0);

    for (startOrdinal; startOrdinal <= endOrdinal; startOrdinal++) {
        chars.push(String.fromCharCode(startOrdinal));
    }

    return chars;

}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QHETq/).

**However**, I agree that the [literal `Array` is a better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8452789/31671)...

- Succinct and to the point.
- You can tell at a glance what the `Array` contains. No need to logically step through the code.
- You can avoid always creating the exact same `Array` with code. The alphabet will never (*rarely?*) change.
- It is one less piece of code to worry about that may contain bugs, etc for a trivial generation of chars.

Comment: which is certainly slower, and therefore not nice.

Comment: It's also much longer and harder to read (hello magic numbers).

Comment: @jAndy I don't think that metric is the best to determine if a solution is best. I'll agree that the literal is easier to read with a *bonus* of negligible cost of generation.

Comment: +1 for the function. If this is needed more than once, or with any amount of flexibility, this would be the way to do it.

Comment: You could get rid of the magic numbers like this: `for (var i = "a".charCodeAt(); i <= "z".charCodeAt(); i++)`

Comment: @alex: Heh, I updated the function to allow for more than just alphabet characters, but now the regex just looks naughty. `/^(.)-(.)$/`

Answer (score 9):

```
alphabet = [];
for (var i = 'a'.charCodeAt(0); i < 'z'.charCodeAt(0); i++)
{
    alphabet.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
}

console.log(alphabet);
```

Comment: You may want to calculate `z`'s charCode once.

Comment: I agree with @alex. I'd hate to recalculate that each time. `while ( z >= a ) alphabet.push(String.fromCharCode(a++));`

Answer (score 3):

*JavaScript* has Array comprehensions and generators added in version 1.7 (2006). It seems they were also [added to ECMAScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Version_correspondence). JScript (IE) doesn't seem to support them.

Array comprehensions allow a succinct solution.

```
var letters = [String.fromCharCode(i) for each (i in range(97, 123))]
```

Where `range` is [as defined here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Array_comprehensions_%28Merge_into_Array_comprehensions%29).

Note: Keeping in mind that currently to use this in Firefox you need to specify the version you want:

```
<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7" src="foo.js">
```

**Come back to this post in 10 years time.**

Answer (score 1):

You could use String.fromCharCode() and a loop to construct it.
for instance 97 trought 122 will do the characters you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'a';
while (!/z/.test(s)) s += String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(s.length-1)+1) 

document.write(s.split(''));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/FTDaR/

Answer (score 0):

Recursive;

```
String.prototype.through = function(z) {
 if (this.charCodeAt(this.length-1) == z.charCodeAt(0)) return this;
    return this + String.fromCharCode(this.charCodeAt(0)+1).through(z)   
}

document.write("a".through("z").split(''))
```

Of course this it not recommended and its not fast.

Or with a different `through` method

```
String.prototype.through = function(z) {
 var start = curr = (''+this).charCodeAt(0);
 var end = z.charCodeAt(0)
 var increment = (start < end) ? 1 : -1;
 var ret = ''+this
 while (curr != end) {
     curr += increment;
     ret += String.fromCharCode(curr);
 }
 return ret;
}
```